# set a javascript value in a html body in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

this is my script in a blade page :

```
function manageRow(data) {
              //alert('inside row'+data);
              var rows = '';
              $.each( data, function( key, value ) {  

                if(value.user_id=={{Auth::user()->id}}){
                  getcomment(value.id);

                  rows+='<div class="post"><div class="user-block">@if($user->sex=='female' && $all->avatar=='default.jpg')<img class="img-responsive img-bordered-sm" src="public/theme/dist/img/default1.jpg" alt="user image">@else<img class="img-responsive img-bordered-sm" src="public/theme/dist/img/{{$all->avatar}}" alt="user image">@endif<span class="username"><a href="#">{{$all->username}}</a><a href="#" class="pull-right btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a><p style="font-size: 10px"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;'+value.created_at+'</p></span></div><p>'+value.status+'</p><ul class="list-inline"><li><a href="#" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up margin-r-5"></i> Like</a></li><li ><a href="#" class="link-black text-sm"><i class="fa fa-comments-o margin-r-5"></i> Comments(5)</a></li></ul><div><form action="{{route('post_comment.store')}}" method="post"><input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="'+value.id+'"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><div class="input-group"><input class="form-control input-sm" name="comment" type="text" placeholder="Type a comment"><span class="input-group-btn"><button  class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm comment-btn2" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></button></span></div></form></div><div class="all-comments"></div></div>';



                }
              });

              $("#status-id").html(rows);

            }

function getcomment(id){

      $(".all-comments").html('<p>awlad</p>');

    }
```

i want to set this html into the rows above

but it prints undefinied instead of awlad..
anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to append value to element `all-comments` when it's not created yet :

```
rows+='<div class="post"><div class="user-block">....';
getcomment(value.id);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually the `getcomment(value.id);` would go after the `$("#status-id").html(rows);` part. `rows` is just a variable.

Comment: What work @leo and what not works? please try to verify the console if there's any errors add them to the OP with more info (like how your page looks like after full load).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the html you are creating will work. You are inserting some blade syntax, but at that time the blade file has already been parsed

Comment: everything is working good without **$(".all-comments").html('<p>awlad</p>');
** this